Mangling (routing mark) not working on iptables as excepted
I'm playing around with iptables, using it as some kind of "DMZ firewall" in my home lab. My server has two interfaces (connecting to two different virtual firewalls) and because of that, I want to routing mark my whole iptables traffic (same subnets needs to connect on both interfaces). The goal is to make it possible to both client subnets to connect from both interfaces. There is a few information from my scenario:
VLAN1000 interface address: 192.168.255.17/30

VLAN2000 interface address: 192.168.255.29/30

Incoming subnets from external FW1 (VLAN1000):
Servers: 192.168.0.0/24
Clients: 192.168.1.0/24

Incoming subnets from external FW2 (VLAN2000):
Servers: 192.168.2.0/24
Clients: 192.168.3.0/24

Two custom routing tables exists in /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
2000     VLAN2000
1000     VLAN1000

Static routes on VLAN1000 (route-VLAN1000):
192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.255.18 dev VLAN1000 table VLAN1000
192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.255.18 dev VLAN1000 table VLAN1000
192.168.3.0/24 via 192.168.255.18 dev VLAN1000 table VLAN1000

VLAN1000 rules (rule-VLAN1000):
from 192.168.255.17/32 table VLAN1000
to 192.168.255.17/32 table VLAN1000
from 192.168.0.0/24 table VLAN1000
to 192.168.0.0/24 table VLAN1000
from 192.168.1.0/24 table VLAN1000
to 192.168.1.0/24 table VLAN1000
from 192.168.3.0/24 table VLAN1000
to 192.168.3.0/24 table VLAN1000

Static routes on VLAN2000 (route-VLAN2000):
192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.255.30 dev VLAN2000 table VLAN2000
192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.255.30 dev VLAN2000 table VLAN2000
192.168.3.0/24 via 192.168.255.30 dev VLAN2000 table VLAN2000

VLAN2000 rules (rule-VLAN2000):
from 192.168.255.29/32 table VLAN2000
to 192.168.255.29/32 table VLAN2000
from 192.168.1.0/24 table VLAN2000
to 192.168.1.0/24 table VLAN2000
from 192.168.2.0/24 table VLAN2000
to 192.168.2.0/24 table VLAN2000
from 192.168.3.0/24 table VLAN2000
to 192.168.3.0/24 table VLAN2000

My config in iptables mangle table:
-A PREROUTING -i VLAN1000 -j MARK --set-mark 1000
-A PREROUTING -i VLAN2000-j MARK --set-mark 2000
-A POSTROUTING -o VLAN1000 -j MARK --set-mark 1000
-A POSTROUTING -o VLAN2000 -j MARK --set-mark 2000
-A FORWARD -i VLAN1000 -j MARK --set-mark 1000
-A FORWARD -o VLAN1000 -j MARK --set-mark 1000

My config in nat table:
-A PREROUTING -i VLAN1000 -m mark --mark 1000 -d 10.0.0.5 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.5:3389
-A POSTROUTING -o VLAN1000 -m mark --mark 1000 -d 192.168.0.5 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.255.17

The config in filter table:
-A FORWARD -i VLAN1000 -m mark --mark 1000 -s 192.168.1.0/24,192.168.3.0/24 -d 192.168.0.5 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i VLAN1000 -m mark --mark 1000 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o VLAN1000 -m mark --mark 1000 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

The documentation available of iptables mangling is very few. What do I miss in my scneraio? Or I misunderstood its working mechanism? Thank you in advance.

I don't really grok what you are trying to do, but for policy routing to be "symmetrically" applied to traffics in a "connection", you'll need CONNMARK as well. Not sure if it's good material, but random Google search gives me this. See if it helps you to get the idea, if that's what you need.

I figured out what the problem was. It wasn't mangling's case, the problem persisted in the routing rules.
Since in one case exact the same rules existed in both rule files, it confused the routing. So for example, instead of adding incomplete rules like this:
from 192.168.1.0/24 table VLAN1000

and
from 192.168.1.0/24 table VLAN2000

Added complete rules that restricted the routing flow and didn't permit all in reverse:
from 192.168.1.0/24 to 192.168.0.0/24 table VLAN1000
from 192.168.0.0/24 to 192.168.1.0/24 table VLAN1000

and
from 192.168.1.0/24 to 192.168.3.0/24 table VLAN2000
from 192.168.3.0/24 to 192.168.1.0/24 table VLAN2000

This change solved my problem.
